# Webdriver not finding element on page

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python to access a div element containing links. Webdriver is unable to find this div for some reason. Other div elements on the page seem like they are randomly findable by webdriver. Here is the html of the page:

[image: Image of html of page]

Highlighted is the div I need to select. All other class names within this div are unfindable too. Codes I have tried for finding elements:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('carouselNav__listWrapper recipeCarousel__listWrapper')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("carouselNav__listWrapper recipeCarousel__listWrapper")
```

Error I am getting:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".carouselNav__listWrapper recipeCarousel__listWrapper"}
> (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.131)

I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No class name do not work with spaces, and in css you can combine them like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".carouselNav__listWrapper.recipeCarousel__listWrapper")
```